# Select All Rows From Union of Two Tables with Same Column

Tags: mysql, sql, row, jupyter

I've read at least 10 SO questions on this topic and am not able to figure this out.  I'm working in Jupyter, but I don't think it makes a difference.

I have two tables:

```
   Table A           Table B
+-----+-----+     +-----+-----+
|  x  |  y  |     |  x  |  y  |
+-----+-----+     +-----+-----+
|  1  |  2  |     |  1  |  3  |
|  2  |  3  |     |  4  |  6  |
|  3  |  4  |     |  7  |  9  |
|  4  |  5  |     |  10 |  12 |
|  5  |  6  |     +-----+-----+
+-----+-----+
```

I'm able to take the union of these tables with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM A UNION SELECT * FROM B
)
```

However, I'm not sure how to go about returning the four rows that have duplicate `x` columns from this union.  I've tried `GROUP BY x HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`, but this only returns 2 rows.  The output should be:

```
+-----+-----+
|  x  |  y  |
+-----+-----+
|  1  |  2  |
|  1  |  3  |
|  4  |  5  |
|  4  |  6  |
+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
select a.*
from a
where exists (select 1 from b where b.x = a.x)
union all
select b.*
from b
where exists (select 1 from a where a.x = b.x);
```

`union` incurs overhead for removing duplicates.  This seems unnecessary in your case.  So, if you don't need duplicate removal, use `union all`.

Comment: Wow, thank you!  What's the reason behind `a.*` and `select 1`?

Comment: @JacobG. Speed.

Comment: @Strawberry I was wondering what they meant as I'm relatively new to SQL, but thanks!  I'm pretty sure the `1` must be referring to the first column.

Comment: @JacobG. No. 1 is 1. It could be anything because we're just testing for 'existence'

Comment: `a.*` returns all the columns from the `a` table, using the table alias.  `select 1` is used with `exists`.  `exists` checks for the existence of a row; it doesn't care what values are on the row; and "1" is simple to type.